# SignalR cross-domain Console Application host with JavaScript client issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, console-application, signalr.client

Im trying to establish a coss-domain connection. In my JavaScript client I see no problem with the connection, but if I send a signal from the hub, the javascript method is not getting hit. In console there is no error displayed. The JavaScript variable "chat" is defined. I looked at sever tutorials in the internet and I mostly copied the code but it doesn't work.

Console Application host:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:43253/";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Server running on {url}");
                Console.ReadKey();
                MyHub hub = new MyHub();
                hub.Send("test", "test");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the cors middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {

                };

                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch is already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("connected");
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
            context.Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

JavaScript client:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="image">
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:43253/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:43253/signalr";
            var chat = $.connection.myHub;

            chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) {
                console.log(name + message);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was i forgot to start the connection. Just added: $.connection.hub.start(); at the end of the JavaScript client